# Finding a good CentOS VPS host

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, looking-for-hosting, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking to host a new Wordpress blog/portfolio on a CentOS VPS. I know that a shared hosting account would do for such requirements. However I want to run NGINX with an opcode and memory cache, as I am a bit of speed queen.

The problem is I don't know who to buy from, and am wary that just because the numbers look good doesn't mean the service is good.

I am happy to stay unmanaged for the time being, and am in two minds whether or not to use cPanel (is pretty expensive, plus I plan on using [Centmin Mod](http://www.centminmod.com/) to ensure things like PHP, NGINX .etc stay up to date).

I was hoping you could provide suggestions of quality hosting providers who are affordable (I don't want to spend much more than $20 a month for the time being, but want an easily upgradeable system should I ever need more resources).

**In short I require:**

- $20 max budget (small room for manoeuvre)
- CentOS (preferably 5.* and 64bit)
- Speed lots of it (I am no expert on the balance of resources, so need a little guidance here)
- an upgradeable plan should the time arise
- A good experience :)

Thanks.